# Calling controllers different methods from view page using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter project in which viwe page having textboxes, radio buttons and button.I fetched textbox values from database and manually enter from date and to date then by clicking on save button insert query gets empty values because in controller i called all functions serially in index function.What is the best solution to call controller methods on each event of view page?

leave_appl_view.php

```
<form action="leave_apply_control/index" method="post" id="myForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Emp ID</label>
                <?php if(!empty($emp_leave)) 
                { 
                    foreach ($emp_leave as $liv)
                    { ?>   
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value="<?php echo $liv->employee_id ?>" >                        
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Employee Name</label>              
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empname" id="empname" value="<?php echo $liv->employee_name ?>" >
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="empmail" id="empmail" value="<?php echo $liv->email ?>" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Leave type: </label>
                <input type="radio"  id="half" name="type" onclick="Checkradiobutton()" value="half"> Half Day
                <input type="radio"  id="full" name="type" onclick="Checkbutton()" value="full" Checked> Full Day
            </div>
        </div>                                              
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group label-floating" id="frm_dt">
                <label class="control-label">From Date: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1" name="from"  ></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group label-floating" id="to_dt">
                <label class="control-label">To Date: </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker2" name="to" ></p>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>                                                  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">                                                                      
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Balance Leaves</label>                                                 
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bal_leave" value="<?php echo $liv->balanced_leaves ?>" >
            </div>
<?php } 
}
?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Applied Leaves</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="totaldays" id="totaldays" readonly>                                               
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Applied Date</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="todayDate" id="todayDate" value="<?php echo date("d/m/Y"); ?>" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                              
    <div class="row">                                                                              
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Reason </label>
                <TEXTAREA class="form-control" id="reason" name="reason"> </TEXTAREA>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="<?php // echo base_url() ?>leave_apply_control/save_data">Apply</button> 
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="<?php echo base_url();?>leave_apply_control" >Reset</button>
</form>
```

---

leave_Apply_control.php

```
<?php
class leave_apply_control extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
        $this->load->library('calendar');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->helper('date');           
    }//contruct close

    function index()
    {      
        $id=$this->session->userdata('id');
        $data['foren_id'] = $this -> user_model -> get_emp_id($id);    
        foreach($data['foren_id'] as $fk)
        {           
            //echo "////control page fk is   ".$fk->emp_id;
        }               
        $data2['emp_leave'] = $this->user_model->get_leave_count($fk->emp_id);                              
        $this->load->view('leave_application',$data2);  
        $this->save_data();
    }

    public function save_data()
    {
        $fd = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('from')));
        $td = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('to')));
        $data = array(
            'employee_id' => $this->input->post('id'),
            'emp_name' => $this->input->post('empname'),
            'leave_from' => $fd,
            'leave_to' => $td,
            'no_of_days' => $this->input->post('totaldays'),
            'applied_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'reason' => $this->input->post('reason'),
            'mail' => $this->input->post('empmail'),
            'leave_type' => $this->input->post('type'),
            'balance_leaves' => $this->input->post('bal_leave'),
            'status' => 1,
        );              
        $this->user_model->insert_leave($data);                     
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Refer documentation first, https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: Did you find the answer for your question. If not im ready to help you to solve...

Comment: Nope, inshort my query is save_data() function is not exceuting. If i merged save data code into index() method then $data2['emp_leave'] founds empty.